# Show soft keyboard when Activity starts

Tags: android, keyboard, soft-keyboard

I have 2 activities, A and B. When A starts, it checks for a condition and if true, it calls `startActivityForResult()` to start B. B only takes text input so it makes sense for the soft keyboard to automatically pop up when B start. When the activity starts, the EditText already has focus and it ready for input.

The problem is that the keyboard never shows up, even with `windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"` set in the manifest under the `<activity>` tag for B. I also tried with the value set to `stateVisible`. Since it doesn't show up automatically, I have to tap the EditText to make it show.

Anyone know what the solution might be?

Comment: (Shooting in the dark, but) have you tried requestFocus on the text box?

Answer (score 103):

What worked best for me is in Android Manifest for activity B adding

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"`

Comment: I should note that so far, this works well for the Nexus One running 2.2 but some of the Motorola devices such as Milestone with 2.1 seem to ignore this.

Comment: Thanks, to do that programmatically check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593053/open-soft-keyboard-programmatically

Comment: Using `stateVisible` results in the keyboard reappearing when the device orientation changes.  If this behaviour is not desired, then `stateVisible` is not the solution.

Comment: For newbies like me: you must add this line right after <activity android:name=".MyActivity"

Comment: The problem with this method is that it can't be propagated to many apps using a central library. You need to repeat this behavior in all manifest files. A programmatic solution solves that problem too.

Answer (score 22):

Easiest solution: Put

```
android:windowSoftInputMode = "stateVisible"
```

in Activity section of AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: For newbies like me: you must add this line right after <activity android:name=".MyActivity"

Answer (score 14):

If requestFocus on an EditText isn't showing it, maybe this'll do it:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(mEditText, 0);
```

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html) for more information.

Comment: this should work so long as you're not specifying a different soft input state anywhere else, like in your manifest or in code. i.e this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

Answer (score 11):

For me worked only this solutions:
add in manifest for that activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```

Comment: Did it work for devices with hardware keyboard? I'm having a hard time working this in hardware keyboard devices i.e 2.2 devices

Comment: For newbies like me: you must add this line right after <activity android:name=".MyActivity"

Answer (score 8):

I have got two way.

**Method 1.** 
Use the following code inside the OnCreate method

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

It will prevent popping up keyboard unless you click.

or

**Method 2** You can move away the focus on other view like TextView by using "requestfocus" in the xml.

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/year_birth_day"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1991">            
           <requestFocus />
           </TextView>
```

**Method 3** ( I think it should be avoidable) Using the following code in the manifest-

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
```

Comment: using <requestFocus/> is the only thing that worked for me.  Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Try showing the keyboard with some delay. Something similar to this:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(yourTextBox, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    };

    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(tt, 200);
}
```

Comment: timer task? for what?

Comment: @busylee you can use a Handler or any other method of executing something in a delay of your choosing. This is only an example.

Comment: There is no reason to use delay

Answer (score 3):

**Major Attention Required!**

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"` This alone won't work to show keyboard on activity start.

You also need to explicitly add this into your class

```
editTextXYZ.requestFocus()
        val imm: InputMethodManager =
            getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.showSoftInput(editTextXYZ, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an emulator, you have to turn the hard keyboard off in order for the soft keyboard to show.

Answer (score 1):

File : AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
```

Add following property :

```xml
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
```

Which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

paste this after setContentView

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```