# need full example of use of softkeyboard

Tags: soft-keyboard

Can someone point me at a complete ap that uses the softkeyboard example -- or something similar?

Comment: Any particular soft keyboard?

Comment: I think you need to add some detail to this question, like language, platform etc.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the soft keyboard is not provided by an individual application but by the underlying OS or some utility installed with the device.  Windows has an on-screen keyboard you can bring up associated with accessability.  Many touch-panel devices have an icon displayed somewhere on the screen that bring up a keyboard that's rendered by the touch-panel itself.  Phones without a built-in keyboard display a virtual keyboard when needed (i.e, iPhone or Android or many many others).

The common thing in all of these devices is that it is not an application providing the input, but something lower level.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this was just an Android group.  Android has an example SoftKeyboard service that I don't understand how to connect to my activity.  I want to modify the keyboard and have it appear at the bottom of my screen.

Comment: This is a general purpose programming Q&A site.  You need to put the particular language and/or platform in the tags of the question you want to ask.  Generally the more specific and detailed the question the better answers you'll get.

Comment: example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466516/show-soft-keyboard-when-activity-starts