# Android Keyboard not showing

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm showing an input box using AlertDialog. The EditText inside the dialog itself is automatically focused when I call AlertDialog.show(), but the soft keyboard is not automatically shown.

How do I make the soft keyboard automatically show when the dialog is shown? (and there is no physical/hardware keyboard). Similar to how when I press the Search button to invoke the global search, the soft keyboard is automatically shown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try the following method once the dialog is open, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593053/how-to-open-soft-keyboard-programmatically):

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(linearLayout.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Other suggestions [here](http://plainoldstan.blogspot.com/2010/09/android-set-focus-and-show-soft.html) too.