# Android ViewPager dimension

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

Does the `ViewPager` have to be the only object present inside the activity layout?
I'm trying to implement something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/reader_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/page_viewer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/miniatures_gallery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /></LinearLayout>
```

Where should I have a big pager scrolling in the top (and I have it) and a smaller gallery scrolling under that.
This shows me only the pager and not the gallery.
Any suggestion?

Comment: try this: http://helpmeco.de/2012/1/android-viewpager-and-gallery-integration

Comment: tnx this was great...but i've got a crash on page rotation, any suggestion for it?

Comment: do you have a stack trace?  did you grab the project from github or did you copy paste from the tutorial?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394681/android-i-am-unable-to-have-viewpager-wrap-content

Comment: updated helpmeco.de link http://responsiveandroid.com/2012/01/26/android-viewpager-and-gallery-integration.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ViewPager does not support `wrap_content` as it (usually) never have all its children loaded at the same time, and can therefore not get an appropriate size (the option would be to have a pager that changes size every time you have switched page).

You can however set a precise dimension (e.g. 150dp) and `match_parent` works as well.
You can also modify the dimensions dynamically from your code by changing the `height`-attribute in its `LayoutParams`.

Comment: What is it that doesn't work with it? Another solution, that works if you want the pager to fill any empty space is this:
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1"/>
Then the pager leaves just enough space for any other views.

Answer (score 5):

Assign layout weight to view pager as 1 & height = 0dp instead of wrap_content

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/page_viewer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Comment: how to implement on RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with a couple of hacks. Here is what it involves:

First, I needed a layout that would ignore `ViewPager`'s height limit. Used it as a parent layout for `ViewPager` items.

```
public class TallLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    public TallLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TallLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TallLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    }
}
```

I then wrote the logic for resizing ViewPager:

```
private class ViewPagerContentWrapper implements OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    public ViewPagerContentWrapper(ViewPager viewPager) {
        mViewPager = viewPager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int position = mViewPager.getCurrentItem(); 
        check(position);
        check(position + 1);
    }

    private void check(int position) {
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) mViewPager.getChildAt(position); 
        View v = vg == null ? null : vg.getChildAt(0);

        if (v != null) {
            int height = v.getHeight();
            if (height > mViewPager.getHeight()) {
                resize(height);
            }
        }
    }

    private void resize(int height) {
        mViewPager.setLayoutParams(
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        height
                )
        );
    }
}
```

Which I registered as global layout listener:

```
viewPager.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewPagerContentWrapper(viewPager));
```

Comment: This will create an infinite layout cycle. Initially system requests onLayout that will call your OnGlobalLayoutListener that will call onLayout that will call OnGlobalLayoutListener and so on...