# Image Slideshow using ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to implement the following screen :

[image: ScreenShot]

In the screen shot you can see that below MyAdvisor TextView i have an image.On swiping this image different image will be displayed .To create Swipe Gallery i am using view pager here.I am using an Adapter which is providing images to display through view pager.

**Adapter:**

```
   public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private int[] images = new int[]{R.drawable.imgone,
            R.drawable.img2,
            R.drawable.img3};

    public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == (ImageView) object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
}
```

Below is the xml file of demo project of mine which contains two text view and a view pager.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_marginTop="15sp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:text="Hello2"
    android:layout_above="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_marginTop="15sp"/>



<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

My problem is that the view pager is having height as match_parent.Even after changing it as wrap_content ,the other views are not displayed .Please guide me how can i implement this screen.

Comment: Post your XML layout file.

Comment: Hard code your view pager height to android:layout_height="200dp" . possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966904/viewpager-in-android-is-taking-full-screen or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532307/android-viewpager-dimension?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `Heterogenous Layouts inside RecyclerView` for that approach.If you're not familiar with the concept, go thru this [tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView).And for the viewpager part, there is this awesome [library](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/wiki/Start-Using) which comes up with so many built in features that you will absolutely love.Just inflate the `Sliderlayout` of this library inside `onCreateViewHolder()` of adapter and provide corresponding data.No need to write your own custom `pageradapter` and handle events.You just have to know how to use `Recyclerview` and you're pretty much done.