# ViewPager not supporting layout_height = wrap_content

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm building an android application with the following layout.[image: application layout]

It's already known that `layout_height="wrap_content"` doesn't work for the ViewPager.

My question is how to change it dynamically. The content of the ViewPager is inflated from two xml layouts, `vp_statistics.xml and vp_campaigns.xml.`

here's the xml for the ViewPager

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/topcontent_wrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewpager_wrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the code for my PagerAdapter

```
class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 2;
}

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int pos){
    LayoutInflater inflater =     (LayoutInflater)collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int resId = 0;
    switch(pos){
    case 0:
        resId = R.layout.vp_statistics;
        break;
    case 1:
        resId = R.layout.vp_campaigns;
        break;
    }

    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);


    ((ViewPager)collection).addView(view, 0);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ((ViewPager)container).removeView((View)object);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0 == ((View)arg1);
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

and inside my onCreate() mthod of the Activity class:

```
MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

Is there a way to get the height of the `vp_statistics.xml` and `vp_campaigns.xml` layouts and assign it dynamically to `ViewPager (@id/viewpager)` every time the `instantiateItem()` object gets called?

Comment: did you fix the problem? I have a similar one.

Comment: did you find the solution for this

Comment: please star issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54604

Answer (score 6):

1. Add a `weightSum=2` attribute to the parent `LinearLayout`, and set `orientation=vertical`.
2. Set the top child LinearLayout's `layout_weight=1`. Also, set `layout_height=0dip`
3. Wrap the ViewPager into another `LinearLayout` with `layout_weight=1` and `layout_height=0dip`

Comment: @bagusflyer if you share your code, we may be able to see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18167273/590947).

The solution **extends** ViewPager to override `onMeasure()` to make `wrap_content` just work for the height.

Answer (score 0):

use `0dp` instead of `wrap_content`, and for dynamically change that

```
pager = new ViewPager(this);
        pager.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work, it actually crashes the application. The right code would be

    `pager.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`

But even with the changed code, it doesn't change the height of the ViewPager.

Answer (score -1):

In order to assign different screen real estate to each linear layout try using the `layout_weight` parameter. You can reassign this in-code to achieve this 'dynamic' weighting change. Overview [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#linearlayout) with plenty of Google-able examples of how to achieve the weight layouts in code...

Comment: What I'm trying to do in my application is not to assign the top layout and the bottom ViewPager a weight in order to give them half of the screen for each, I'm trying to assign different values to the height of the ViewPager each time the ViewPager page changes, because the layouts that represent the ViewPager pages are different in height. And, for example if the first page has the height of 200dp and I assign the viewpager layout_height="200dp", when changing to the second page (which is 400dp) the bottom 200dp are hidden!

Comment: Hey Andrei, It sounds like you need to measure the view after it has been drawn and update your view pager width and height after the draw has completed. I embarked on a similar task recently whilst embedding Google Charts into WebViews. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4406090/1348379) on the topic. It will help you out.

Answer (score -2):

Use **RelativeLayout**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout" >

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```