# ViewPager does not wrap height to its content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

ViewPager does not wrap its height to its content. For my layout I need to set the height dynamically because it is nested in other layouts.
Therefore I created a ScrollView as content of the ViewPager and check its height in onCreate method of the Fragment, but the ScrollView has always the same size.
How can I wrap height of the ViewPager to fit to its content?

```
        final ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.sv);

        ViewTreeObserver vto = sv.getViewTreeObserver(); 
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                int height = sv.getMeasuredHeight();
                //always same height independent of content height
                //need to resize ViewPager



                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) mPager.getLayoutParams();
                params.height = height;
                mPager.setLayoutParams(params);
            } 
        });
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394681/android-i-am-unable-to-have-viewpager-wrap-content which have a more appropriate answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tried a lot of things, finally got it.
-initially set the ViewPager to a big height to fit all possible content and not to make its height reduced
-had to nest 2 LinearLayout to get the correct height.
hth

Comment: could you post some sample code of your layout with your fix?

Comment: ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) mPager.getLayoutParams();
                params.height = height;
                mPager.setLayoutParams(param.heigt);