# Adjust RelativeLayout wrapper to size of ImageView in a PagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-pageradapter

I have an xml file that represents a slide that gets loaded by a custom PagerAdapter:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/slideWrap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ccc"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivSlide"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/slide_im_putting_face"
        android:contentDescription="image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtSlide"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
        android:lines="3"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:hint="@string/main_hint"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How do I adjust the slideWrap container to be the exact same dimensions as the scaled ImageView? Not quite sure how to do this a PagerAdapter.

Comment: Have you tried using `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` for the `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: I have, the wrapper still has extra height or width pixels depending on the orientation.

Comment: Where are you seeing these `extra height or width pixels`? I am using your layout file. Are you referring to the white area at the bottom in portrait orientation?

Comment: @vikram - Yes, there is always extra space underneath in portrait mode, or to the right in landscape. The relative layout parent is never the same dimensions as the imageview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the extra white space was because the ViewPager, apparently you cannot set wrap content for your height: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8532550/641738

Instead, I just calculated a few percentages based on the static width/height of all my slides and set the wrapper accordingly. I could have just set the slide dimensions in their respective dp layout folders, but that seemed like a hassle. Seems to work fairly well on a few handheld devices so far as long as all the slides are the same dimensions. The percentages were somewhat trial and error:

```
    // Check the display and make the necessary adjustments for Portrait mode
    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0 || display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180) {
        double width = display.getWidth() * 0.93;
        double adjustedHeight = width * 0.85;
        wrapLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)width, (int)adjustedHeight);
    }
    else {
        double height = display.getHeight() * 0.73;
        double adjustedWidth = height * 1.15;
        wrapLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)adjustedWidth, (int)height);
    }

    slideWrap.setLayoutParams(wrapLayoutParams);
```