# Change view pager height to wrap content with the content height of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using 3 `ViewPagers` on a single `LinearLayout`. and i want to set the height of `ViewPager` to `wrap_content` dynamically.
My fragment is loaded in `ViewPager` dynamically also. So on page change if the fragment's height is more than the viewpager's height then the viewpager's height should be automatically increased.

Layout is like

[image]

Please suggest what to do?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the "wrap_content" doesn't seem to be working with the View pager.
Here is the solution:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){

    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int height = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {

        View child = getChildAt(i);

        child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

        int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();

        if(h > height) height = h;

    }

    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
}
```

reference:
[Android: I am unable to have ViewPager WRAP_CONTENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394681/android-i-am-unable-to-have-viewpager-wrap-content)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the implementation looks as follows,

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
    <ViewPager />
    <ViewPager />
    <ViewPager />
</LinearLayout>
```

then setting the height of the ViewPagers to `wrap_content` should have the desired result. There is no need to do this dynamically. Otherwise, if you really want/need to do it dynamically, just set the ViewPager layoutParams to the following from code:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
viewPager.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

The parameters in the LayoutParams constructor are (width, height), and you need to change the width if you don't want that to be wrap_content.

Comment: i tried with that, but then no viewpager is displaying on screen. they are getting the height as 0. And also i need to change it dynamically on page change because some time i got the textview in viewpager more lengthy

Comment: same problem is with me. I am getting no item on the screen

Comment: Sorry for the late response (holidays). Did you guys ever manage to fix it? Otherwise I'll look into it again.

Comment: same problem with me,did you guys get solution.?

Comment: If it's ok that all viewpagers have the same height, then set the height to 0px, and add a layout weight of 1.

Comment: Any suggestion? I have the same issue.

Comment: @bagusflyer; I think you should ask a new question, since I'm not able to help you like this.