# Android: A ViewPager that wrap content in each page

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I want to make a ViewPager in a scrollview, and i know that a viewpager with scroll that's inside a scrollview wont be a good practise. In the case i thought of adapting the height of viewpager to wrap_content, so the size of the scrollview would change depending on the child of the viewpager.

I have found some solutions in here, but it didn't work, and i was wondering if there is anyone that already had found a solution for this. The closest i got to a solution was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18167273/1842694), but it only set's the height of the first shown child, and in my case the height of the fragments can vary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can. in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18167273/1842694) solution code

change

`View view = getChildAt(0);`

to

`View view = getChildAt(getCurrentItem());`