# how to add class to a ViewPager programmatically

Tags: java, android, class

in this question i Found the following code
[Android: I am unable to have ViewPager WRAP_CONTENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394681/android-i-am-unable-to-have-viewpager-wrap-content/18167273#18167273)

```
<view
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
class="de.cybergen.ui.layout.WrapContentHeightViewPager"
android:id="@+id/wrapContentHeightViewPager"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
```

how i can set class programmatically for ViewPager.
i have a code like this:

```
ViewPager vp = new ViewPager(this);
PagesAdapter dp = new PagesAdapter(this);// this class extends PagerAdapter
vp.setAdapter(dp);
```

i want to use class (WrapContentHeightViewPager) to set Wrap content height ViewPager.

Comment: show us more of your code. This single line you posted tells us nothing about what you want to acheive and what your problem is.

Comment: please check the link to see class WrapContentHeightViewPager. i want to set wrap_content height for viewpager. i created ViewPager by java code, but in that question by xml!.

Comment: Just use that class instead of `ViewPager`?

Comment: yes yes! how use that class by code java, dont xml !