# NestedScrollview + Coordinator Layout + SmartTabLayout having viewpager with fragments scroll infinite issue

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

Below are two images for strange behaviour

[Layout Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUhJ2.jpg)

[NestedScrollview has infinite space and it scrolls and scrolls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSHAv.jpg)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical">


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        tools:ignore="ExtraText">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/theme_color" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/cardviewLogin"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/eighteen_dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


            <io.tnine.lifehacks_.customviews.MyTabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/viewpagertab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_height_"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="4dp"
                app:stl_defaultTabTextColor="@color/select_color"
                app:stl_defaultTabTextHorizontalPadding="18dp"
                app:stl_defaultTabTextSize="@dimen/sixteen"
                app:stl_dividerColor="@color/transparent_black_hex_11"
                app:stl_dividerThickness="0dp"
                app:stl_indicatorColor="@color/tab_background"
                app:stl_indicatorCornerRadius="18dp"
                app:stl_indicatorGravity="center"
                app:stl_indicatorInterpolation="smart"
                app:stl_indicatorThickness="36dp"
                app:stl_underlineColor="@color/transparent_black_hex_11"
                app:stl_underlineThickness="0dp" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This is the xml layout file.What i want to achieve is that when the user scrolls the recyclerview in one of the fragment contained in viewpager the whole screen should autoscroll that is happening by the way but the nestedscrollview scrolls and scrolls. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are using `NestedScrollView` **outside** the `CoordinatorLayout`.

Try using `NestedScrollView` **inside** the `CoordinatorLayout` and `ViewPager` inside the `NestedScrollView`.

---

> CoordinatorLayout is **a super-powered `FrameLayout`**.
>
> CoordinatorLayout is intended for two primary use cases:
>
> 1. ***As a top-level application*** decor or chrome layout
> 2. As a container for a specific interaction with one or more child views

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout

**Take a look:** [ViewPager in a NestedScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580954/viewpager-in-a-nestedscrollview)

Answer (score 0):

You can make this work without using `NestedScrollView` .

Use the code below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/whiteColor">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/tab_background"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:elevation="0dp"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:titleTextColor="@color/theme_color" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fourDp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="@dimen/fourDp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/batman"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:text="@string/sign_in"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/sixteen" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/google"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/eighteen_dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <io.tnine.lifehacks_.customviews.MyTabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/viewpagertab"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_height_"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="4dp"
                app:stl_defaultTabTextColor="@color/select_color"
                app:stl_defaultTabTextHorizontalPadding="18dp"
                app:stl_defaultTabTextSize="@dimen/sixteen"
                app:stl_distributeEvenly="true"
                app:stl_dividerColor="@color/transparent_black_hex_11"
                app:stl_dividerThickness="0dp"
                app:stl_indicatorColor="@color/tab_background"
                app:stl_indicatorCornerRadius="18dp"
                app:stl_indicatorGravity="center"
                app:stl_indicatorInterpolation="linear"
                app:stl_indicatorThickness="@dimen/fortydp"
                app:stl_underlineColor="@color/transparent_black_hex_11"
                app:stl_underlineThickness="0dp"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="scrollable" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But this will not make your `CollapsingToolbarLayout` collapse.
For that you should add the following code in your `RecyclerView` .

```
 hacksRecycler.isNestedScrollingEnabled = true
```

set nestedscrolling to true and Voila..!!