# Android NestedScrollView doesn't work in layout with viewpager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-nestedscrollview

This is my layout:
[image]

I want to be able to scroll upper parth of the layout (with name, image, textviews for followers/following...) when I scroll recyclerView in viewPager, so I read that I can use NestedScrollView to implement that, so I put NestedScrollView as my root layout:

```
NestedScrollView:
-----------------ConstraintLayout:
---------------------------------rest of the views as in picture above
```

I also added android:fillViewport="true" in NEstedScrollView because that solves a broblem of missing view pager.
So the problem is that scroll view doesn't work, everything is same as before uting nestedScrollView , bottom part of my layout doesn't scroll of the screen while I scroll recyclerView. Doesn anyone know why, am I using nested scrollView wrong, I haven't found any example that can solve my problem and documentation is really bad.
XML code for my layout:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:id="@+id/title"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:title="UserName"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_profile_24dp"
                tools:src="@drawable/ic_profile_24dp"
                app:civ_border_color="@color/primaryLightColor"
                app:civ_border_width="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/profile_image"
                tools:text="Short description "/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/questions_label"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/questions"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/followers_label"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/questions_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="0"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/questions_label"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/questions_label"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/questions_label"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/followers_label"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/followers"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/questions_label" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/following_label" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/following_label"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/following"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/followers_label" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/followers_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="0"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/followers_label"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/followers_label"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/followers_label"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/following_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="0"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/following_label"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/following_label"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/following_label"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/primaryLightColor"
                app:tabMode="fixed" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/followers_number"/>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sliding_tabs" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**EDIT:** code after suggestion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:id="@+id/title"
                tools:title="UserName"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                    app:civ_border_color="@color/secondaryDarkColor"
                    app:civ_border_width="1dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_profile_24dp"
                    tools:src="@drawable/ic_profile_24dp" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/profile_image"
                    tools:text="Short description "/>

            <include
                    layout="@layout/qff_layout"
                    android:id="@+id/qff_layout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/primaryLightColor"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/qff_layout"/>

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sliding_tabs" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

What is wrong here, It doesn't make any sense, nothing scrolls except ViewPager

Comment: Have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33385207/5110595)

Comment: like I said I did try with fillViewPort = true and it solved the problem of missing view pager but not scrolling of the upper part of the layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know NestedScrollView has one child and the height of his child must be `wrap_content` if you want scroll behavior for your layout.

In your first layout, you must set the height of your `ConstraintLayout` to `wrap_content` but if you want your layout to be `match_parent` for whatever reason (such as you want to bound your ViewPager in the bottom of your layout) you must use suggested answer(it means you must use `CoordinatorLayout`) but with the following consideration:

1- You should put all your stuff you want to scroll in the `AppbarLayout`.This layout extended from `LinearLayout` so you can easily put your stuff into it. from your question, I think you want to scroll all stuff above your `ViewPager` but you may change it as you want.

(Note: actually, I recommend using `CollapsingToolbar` as a child of your `AppbarLAyout` and then put your stuff into it but for your question, this is work perfectly too)

2- Add `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"` attribute in the root of your stuff within your `AppbarLayout`

3- Add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` attribute to the sibling of your `AppbarLayout`. In your question, you use this attribute in your `NestedScrollView`.

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"//I forget too add this, so I edit my answer
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/profile_image"
                tools:text="Short description " />

            <include
                layout="@layout/qff_layout"
                android:id="@+id/qff_layout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#559735"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/qff_layout"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sliding_tabs" />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I didn't try this code but I'm pretty sure this is work for you :)

Comment: I just tried this, and everything you wrote seems to make sense, but it didn;t change anything, upper part above viewpager does not scroll.

Comment: I make a big mistake remove toolbar in AppbarLayout or just put it in your `ConstraintLayout` or add `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"` attribute into it same as his sibling. this time I try it and it worked. sorry for my mistake. hope you enjoy it.

Comment: I just tried it and it did work. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this one :

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
...<AppbarLayout>
......<Toolbar/>
...</AppbarLayout>
...<NestedScrollView> (set height and weight to match parent, then set fillViewPort="true" and for the last give layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior")
......<ConstraintLayout> (change height to wrap_content because you don't need to set match parent, its already handled by nestedscrollview as a parent)
.........(All Child Components)
......</ConstraintLayout>
...</NestedScrollView>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

From official documentation FillViewPort as an NestedScrollView Attributes is to stretch content's height to the viewport boundaries. Please check official document for better explanation :
[NestedScrollView - FillViewPort](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html#setFillViewport(boolean))

**UPDATE :** 
Based on your current code I make some change, please check it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:id="@+id/title"
                tools:title="UserName"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                    app:civ_border_color="@color/secondaryDarkColor"
                    app:civ_border_width="1dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_profile_24dp"
                    tools:src="@drawable/ic_profile_24dp" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/profile_image"
                    tools:text="Short description "/>

            <include
                    layout="@layout/qff_layout"
                    android:id="@+id/qff_layout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/primaryLightColor"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/qff_layout"/>

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sliding_tabs" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this but it nothing changes, it is literally the same as before, Nothing except viewpager scrolls, I don't get it, it doesn't make sense. Please check my edited question , I posted code for your suggestion.

Comment: sorry didn't make it clear, please change the **Constraint Layout height into wrap content instead match parent**

Comment: I tried it with that change and it is still the same, nothing changed

Comment: that's interesting, seems like your viewpager has 0dp height, that's mean forced viewpager height to match with current viewport left. I what you tried to achieve is same with this one, check this out [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580954/viewpager-in-a-nestedscrollview]

Answer (score 0):

Your content fit in your display area. that's why it happened. For that, you have to set fix height of your ViewPager. After that your whole layout scroll. But this is not a proper solution.

**Example**

> set ViewPager height **500dp** and check it.

Comment: it did work, but upper part of the leayout above view pager scrolls of the screen only after the end of the recyclerview in viewpager is reached

Comment: For that, you have to handle programmatically. when you get view pager the last index then scrolls recycler view.

Answer (score 0):

I used `HorizontalScrollView` as a container for the upper layout:

```xml
<ConstraintLayout>

    <Toolbar/>

    <HorizontalScrollView>
        <ConstraintLayout android:id="@+id/top_container">

                <!-- your upper widgets here -->

        </ConstraintLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <TabLayout/>
    <ViewPager/>

</ConstraintLayout>
```

When the user scrolls the `ViewPager`, it callbacks the [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager/widget/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageScrolled(int,%20float,%20int)).
You can override it to programmatically scroll the upper layout by [HorizontalScrollView.setScrollX()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScrollX(int)) method, inherited from the base `View` class:

```
class ScrollListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private ViewGroup scrollView;

    ScrollListener(ViewGroup scrollView) {
        this.scrollView = scrollView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        scrollView.setScrollX(scrollView.getWidth() * position + positionOffsetPixels);
    }

// the interface requires to override 2 more methods:
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
}
```

Then in the `MainActivity` you have to set this Listener to the `ViewPager` by [ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager/widget/ViewPager#addOnPageChangeListener(androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewGroup scrollView = findViewById(R.id.top_scroll);

        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ScrollListener(scrollView));
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 3));
}
```

**Notice:** This code will compact the upper layout, because `HorizontalScrollView` don't use screen bounds to measure and to layout. Thus, it allows you to put widgets off the screen ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYdtk.png)) and gives the ability to scroll.

In your case there are no widgets off the screen, so you won’t see the result, because there’s nothing to scroll. For the test, I added a couple of lines in `MainActivity` to stretch the upper layout:

```
        Point size = new Point();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);

        ConstraintLayout upperLayout = findViewById(R.id.top_container);
        upperLayout .setMinWidth(size.x + 400);
```

My git source code **example**: [link](https://github.com/Unfinite-clouds/ViewPagerWithScroll) (there I removed scroll by touch for upper layout)

Hope this helps, good luck!