# ViewPager not working if set layout_height = wrap_content

Tags: android

I got issues when worked with `ViewPaper`. 
It doesn't show anything when I set ViewPaper's `height = wrap_content` and it shows if I set height for `ViewPager` (ex: `android:layout_height= "350dp"`). Please help!
Thanks!

This is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#FF0000"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Quick Links"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

                <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                    android:id="@+id/circlePage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >
                </com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <com.custom.ExpandableHeightListView
                android:id="@+id/lvAdmissions"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:divider="@drawable/bg_listview_divider"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:listSelector="@drawable/selector_animation" >
            </com.custom.ExpandableHeightListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Resolved**: I follow this link and it help me resolved this issues. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24666987/1928560

Answer (score 12):

ViewPager height must either be specified `match_parent` or you must specify a value for it. Two solutions,

1. Use **weights** concept inside `LinearLayout`
   or
2. Use `onMeasure` method in your class file. Refer [Android: I am unable to have ViewPager WRAP_CONTENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394681/android-i-am-unable-to-have-viewpager-wrap-content)

This is how you can use weights in your `LinearLayout`

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Quick Links"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

            <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/circlePage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >
            </com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.custom.ExpandableHeightListView
            android:id="@+id/lvAdmissions"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:divider="@drawable/bg_listview_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/selector_animation" >
        </com.custom.ExpandableHeightListView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

This way your viewpager layout and ExpandableListView shares equal height. You can change the ratio by changing the weight value

Answer (score 10):

=>100% working when viewpager height set wrap_content.

```
public class FollowUseWrapHeightViewPager extends ViewPager {
public FollowUseWrapHeightViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public FollowUseWrapHeightViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int height = 0;
    View view = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        view = getChildAt(i);
        view.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        int h = view.getMeasuredHeight();
        if(h > height) height = h;
    }

    if (height != 0) {
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    }

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec, view));
}

/**
 * Determines the height of this view
 *
 * @param measureSpec A measureSpec packed into an int
 * @param view the base view with already measured height
 *
 * @return The height of the view, honoring constraints from measureSpec
 */
private int measureHeight(int measureSpec, View view) {
    int result = 0;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

    if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        result = specSize;
    } else {
        // set the height from the base view if available
        if (view != null) {
            result = view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            result = Math.min(result, specSize);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: all child height get one by one and set it's height in viepager

Comment: yep, it works.
It actually get you started in a pretty much right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am also using this, kindly give it a try and see if it solves your problem.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It didn't worked. What I expect it should be include page indicator on this. Anyway, thanks for your comment.