# Viewpager with fragments of different size

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to create a viewpager which contains fragments of different size. The viewpager should resize to the height of fragment current on screen.

Comment: All possible solutions are posted here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394681/android-i-am-unable-to-have-viewpager-wrap-content

Comment: Already tried those not working. The one which selects max of the children  does but I wanted the height of the current one