# ViewPager and ViewPagerIndicator inside RelativeLayout making RelativeLayout expand through whole screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-xml, viewpagerindicator

**This is what is causing me many problems:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/galleryLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:background="@color/white">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/circlePageIndicator"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_middle"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Right now this code **kind of** works only because I've set RelativeLayout's height to 180dp but I don't want to have it this way. I want the whole thing to have height according to ViewPager's child.

There are exactly 2 problems if I set RelativeLayout's height to WrapContent.

**Problem 1**

ViewPager will expand throughout the whole screen. It just doesn't respect it's *wrap_content* height attribute. But I've partially solved that with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20784791/2454356). I'd still appreciate if there's a better solution though.

**Problem 2**

I want have CirclePageIndicator on the bottom of it's parent (RelativeLayout) so I've added attribute *layout_alignParentBottom="true"* but now because of this, the RelativeLayout will expand throughout the whole screen for some reason.

So what I'm trying to have is a RelativeLayout which wraps around ViewPager which wraps around it's child. The child is downloaded from web so I can't pre-set it. And on the bottom of that RelativeLayout, I want to have a ViewPagerIndicator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the **problem 1** you solved the issue correctly, `ViewPager` will not wrap its children by default.

As for the second **problem**, this is a normal `RelativeLayout` behaviour. If you set its `height` to `wrap_content` and add two children, one with `layout_alignParentTop="true"` and second one with `layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, they will stretch your `layout` height-wise.

What you should do is: ask yourself if you really need `RelativeLayout`. If you've provided the whole layout of yours I don't see a need for `RelativeLayout` (its costly). Vertical `LinearLayout` would do just fine. If you decide that you really need `RelativeLayout`, try changing your `Indicator's` rule from `layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to `android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewPager"`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that I want the Indicator "inside" the ViewPager, not below it. So I see no other way but to use RelativeLayout.

Comment: you can always use `FrameLayout` (`Indicator` with `layout_gravity="bottom"`)

Comment: Hm, that is an interesting idea. I haven't thought of that. I can't try this right now but I will as soon as I get home. I'll get back at you and accept your answer if it works. Thanks!