# ViewPager Height to Wrap_Content

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am developing an application and i want to add a `ViewPager` in xml.

My question is how to set height "Wrap_Content" to `ViewPager`?

Comment: can u add your layout file for the reference

Comment: yes i already addedd it

Comment: what have u tried..??/

Comment: basically my imageview shows exactly on screen but text below that is not shown on small screen devices even if i added a scroll view on it.

Comment: unable to see your xml brother can u plz check again

Comment: i also added that extend viewpager (onMeasure ) solution solution but it not work for my case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: I am unable to have ViewPager WRAP\_CONTENT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394681/android-i-am-unable-to-have-viewpager-wrap-content)

Comment: @Rami I try this solution but not work

Comment: without your code we can't figure out the problem

Comment: @ShirishKulkarni So post some code to see why is not working.

Comment: I already went through this with ViewPager.  ViewPager can't use wrap_content for height.   New views are created and destroyed by the adapter as the user is swiping, so ViewPager doesn't have the necessary input to compute a height.  You will need to explicitly set a height value or use match_parent.  Otherwise, override `onMeasure()` to generate the correct height for your paged views.

Comment: I just want to add a viewpager which will half of the screen.