# ViewPager getChildCount returns zero

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

Does anyone know what might cause `viewPager.getChildCount()` to return zero? I do `findViewById` inside onCreate and there I also do `viewPager.setAdapter` and `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)`. Then inside `onResume` I log the child count and it is zero! Why is that?

Oh, btw, the layout of the ViewPager displays no problem although getChildCount returns 0.

I was under the impression that after I call `viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter)` then the ViewPager and the PagerAdapter would have the same count. But clearly that is not true. So why might this be happening?

**UPDATE**

You guys raise some very good points. Thank you. The objective is that I want to iterate through all the Fragments in my ViewPager/PagerAdapter. When I use `getChildCount` it is often 0 at unexpected times, but when it is non-zero everything works fine.

```
for(int i=0; i<viewPager.getChildCount(); i++){
   MyFragmentInterface frag = pagerAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(i);
   . . .  
}
```

However when I use `viewPager.getAdapter().getCount()`, the value is always the same as `pagerAdapter.getCount()`. But I tend to get NullPointerException because apparently there are no fragments yet.

```
for(int i=0; i<viewPager.getAdapter().getCount(); i++){
   MyFragmentInterface frag = pagerAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(i);
   . . .  
}
```

**ANSWER**

I seem to have fixed it with

```
for(int i=0; i<pagerAdapter.getCount(); i++){
  Fragment frag = pagerAdapter.getItem(i);
  . . .
}
```

No more NullPointerException or size 0

Comment: could you please share code snippets

Comment: **ViewPager.getAdapter().getCount()**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as far i know ViewPager doesn't implement this method

> **ViewPager.getChildCount() == ViewGroup.getChildCount()**

but as you see:

```
public abstract class ViewGroup extends View implements ViewParent, ViewManager {


// Number of valid children in the mChildren array, the rest should be null or not
// considered as children
private int mChildrenCount

/**
 * Returns the number of children in the group.
 *
 * @return a positive integer representing the number of children in
 *         the group
 */
public int getChildCount() {
    return mChildrenCount;
}
```

it returns a   **mChildren** count - count of view group child views**

so in short:

** this mean any child view  (that is not the same as object/item of pager)

further see method:

```
ViewPager.populate(int newCurrentItem)
```

ViewPager rely on TabLayout  - so term item is an "tablayout" tab  mapped to view pager adapter item ( could be fragment or view)

as you can add child views to any view - this is not the same as add view pager item to it - you can have something like

```
        [   T1   ][   T2   ][   T3   ]   <- tab layout 
< -- >  |----------------------------|
pager   |[      pager item         ] |  < - fragment  as view pager item 
(view)  |----------------------------|
< -- >  |[   child view of pager    ]|  < - child view of pager
```

> *Thanks for the education, friend. +1. Do you know how I might solve the problem of iterating through my fragments? – Nouvel Travay*

to iterate:  ?? mhh let me think ....

maybe get array and iterate ???

1) **via loop** :)

```
List<Fragment> fragments = getAdapter().getArrayOfFragments();

for(Fragment fragment : fragments) {

   String title = fragment.getTitle();

}
```

2) or **via iterator** :))

```
List<Fragment> fragments = some implementation of List interface;

Iterator<Fragment> iterator = fragments.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {

    Fragment fragment = iterator.next();
}
```

hint  for simplest method to get array ?:

```
 // its only a hint how  - not solution - class need override methods from base class 
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   private List<Items> _items;
   public List<Items> getItems() { return _items; }

   MyAdapter(List<Items> items)
     _items = items;
   }

}

// set 
ViewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(listOfItems);
// retrieve 
Adapter  adapter = ViewPager.getAdapter();
if(adapter != null && MyAdapter.class.isAssignableFrom(adapter.getClass())  {
   // magic 
    MyAdapter myadapter = (MyAdapter) adapter; 
    List<Items>  myList = myAdapter.getItems()
}
```

ps. sorry for typos i dont' know english and i'm bot in real time :D

TODO FOR YOU (FOR TODAY)

- general read about java language
- datatypes, classes, interfaces
- inheritance
- ps. i forgot about *generics*

then try write simple class which inherits from other class and implements a mhhh 
this interface :

```
/**
* Created by ceph3us on 03.09.2015.
*/
public interface IListAdapter<T> extends ListAdapter{
   void add(T listElement);
   void addAll(List<T> listOfElements);
   void clear();
   void remove(T listElement);
   void notifyDataSetChanged();
   T  getItem(int position);
   List<T> getList();
}
```

### as for your case :)

**you have a holder** [ in java term "definition" ] for an array (primitive) of fragments

```
private Fragment registeredFragments[] = new Fragment[FRAGMENT_TITLES.length];
```

**when u fill this array ??**

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return DogsFragment.newInstance();   <-   ?? **here** ??
```

i guess *no* ?? :)

maybe try adjust something like ??

```
        case 0:
             // if my array contains this type of fragment return it 
             // else  make new one ??? and pack to this array ??? 
            return DogsFragment.newInstance();
```

### second matter is instantiation of this holder ???

[FRAGMENT_TITLES.length]  ??  make array of  ?? what size ???

don't use primitive  array for this ( think forward when u will add new fragment - as newbie try use list - at this level It will save you time for looking to solutions for many problems ....

**i say it one more time READ ABOUT INTERFACES ESPECIAL ABOUT ONE named**

```
 List
```

Comment: You are right! ViewPager does not implement the method. But I have relied on it on a recent project and it worked. What might be the problem here? is it android version?

Comment: Thanks for the education, friend. +1. Do you know how I might solve the problem of iterating through my fragments?

Comment: `.getArrayOfFragments()`: is this a method I have to create? I have updated to include my PagerAdapter code. Again whenever `getChildCount` would work I have no problem.

Comment: @NouvelTravay - yes  - I wrote it for you i read in mind :D  joke

Comment: @NouvelTravay  read what i write that doesn't  hurt  - try to learn to understand ...

Comment: I am checking this as the answer so people looking for help may know there is an answer here: the answer is in the post/question