# View Pager wrap content issue

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-wrap-content

I m trying to set view pager height to wrap_content using this [Android: I am unable to have ViewPager WRAP_CONTENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394681/android-i-am-unable-to-have-viewpager-wrap-content)

But it's leaving extra white space at the bottom

How do I remove this space?

This is my xml code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <com.test.android.custom_views.WrapContentHeightViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/similarRecipesPager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

            </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: post whole xml code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: I am unable to have ViewPager WRAP\_CONTENT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394681/android-i-am-unable-to-have-viewpager-wrap-content)

Answer (score 2):

Try This, Overriding onMeasure of your `ViewPager` as follows will make it get the height of the biggest child it currently has.

```
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int height = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
        if(h > height) height = h;
    }

    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use WRAP_CONTENT to define your height, and the content is not big enough you will have extra space, because that is the intended behaviour.

If I had understood you correctly, you want your ViewPager to occupy all the possible space of your activity / fragment where other views are in play as well.

If you want a ViewPager that takes all the space available, you should use the `weight` property of your `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ViewPager android:id="@+id/my_view_pager"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/other_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This way no matter the content of your viewPager, it will fill all the extra white space.