# NestedSCrollView not scrolling fully in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have a `NestedSCrollView` inside `CoordinatorLayout`. In the `NestedSCrollView`there is a `ViewPager`. I put a fragment view in it containing `WebView`. The problem is that if the text in the `WebView` is very long it gets cut and I can't scroll. How to solve this?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nest_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This is the fragment xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<WebView
android:id="@+id/appearance"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
    />
```

[image: problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ViewPager` does not support `wrap_content`. So it has to be precise or `match parent`.

Another solution is to override `OnMeasure` method of the `ViewPager`. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20784791/6806477).