# ViewPager rendering delay using swipe gestures

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I'm having a strange issue using `TabLayout` with `ViewPager`. When I swipe tabs, only a fraction of a text is shown for a short period of time. If I select tabs there is no such problem. What could be wrong?

[image: issue]

Edit:
I have overriden the `onMeasure` method of my `ViewPager`:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    if(null != getAdapter()) {

        int height = 0;
        View child = ((FragmentPagerAdapter) getAdapter()).getItem(getCurrentItem()).getView();
        if (child != null) {
            child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            height = child.getMeasuredHeight();

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN && height < getMinimumHeight()) {
                height = getMinimumHeight();
            }
        }

        getLayoutParams().height = height;
    }

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

This sets height on every `ViewPager` fragment dynamically. Maybe this has something to do with the problem?

Comment: are you doing something in `setOnUserVisibleHint`?

Comment: @VeneetReddy no.

Comment: Stop right here. Why would you re-calculate the height of the page in "onMeasure"? Are you aware of the performance consequences? This looks wrong big time...

Comment: @Mike How to set dynamic height on viewpager then? If the text in the tab is very long it gets cut and I can't scroll. I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394681/android-i-am-unable-to-have-viewpager-wrap-content/) question.

Comment: Have the fragment match_parent and the TextView's height inside your fragment's layout wrap_content. That's it.

Comment: @Mike I already tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834846/nestedscrollview-not-scrolling-fully-in-coordinatorlayout

Comment: Do you need the CoordinatorLayout? Because based on the current designs, it doesn't seem so. If the problem is specifically with that, remove it. Other than that, you should follow the official docs rather than wrong StackOverflow suggestions. Just my 2 cents :) https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: @Mike Yes, I have collapsible toolbar in it. Thanks, I'll try to follow that.

Comment: @Mike your provided docs says nothing about ViewPager's dynamic height. So why would he follow that if it has nothing to do with the needed feature?

Answer (score 0):

Please set your off Screen Page limit to number of tab you have in your fragment.

Example : 
In OnCreate method :

```
 final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_dairy);
       viewPager.setAdapter(new TabsDairyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

       viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5 );  //  5 is number of tab you have
```

worked for me :)

Comment: Now the remaining text doesn't appear at all :/

Comment: Okay , Please try with OffScreenPagelimit to Zero;

viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);

Comment: Again, full text is being displayed on delay. Maybe the problem is with the custom adapter? I've overriden `onMeasure` method on it so it could dynamically change the height.