# Android viewpager not showing?

Tags: android, xml, android-viewpager

I have this layout

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_cover_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="@color/com_facebook_button_background_color_pressed" />
        <refractored.controls.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageProfile"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header_cover_image"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header_cover_image"
            android:background="#ebca0707"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="24dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/add_friend"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/played" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/drop_down_option_menu"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/wins"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/drop_down_option_menu"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/userStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/user_name"
                android:text="Status"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

   <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/profilePager"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
           android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@+id/profile_layout"
           android:elevation="6dp"
           android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
              android:id="@+id/pager"
              android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
      </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The last LinearLayout shows the Tabs but when i switch them there is no viewpager data whatsoever . I tried creating another layout for the tablayout but it still wont work .. Im calling this from a fragment as follows :

```
 public class ProfileFragment : Fragment
    {
        private static Context _context;
        private static Xamarin.Facebook.Profile _profile;
        private CircleImageView imgProfile;
        private TextView userName;
        private TabLayout tabLayout;
        private ViewPager viewpager;
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public static Fragment NewInstance(Activity context , Xamarin.Facebook.Profile profile)
        {
            _context = context;
            _profile = profile;
           Fragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
            return fragment;
        }
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            View view =  inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragmentProfile, container, false);
            imgProfile = view.FindViewById<CircleImageView>(Resource.Id.imageProfile);
            tabLayout =view.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tab_layout);
            viewpager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.pager);
            userName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.user_name);
            userName.Text = _profile.Name;
            Picasso.With(_context).Load(_profile.GetProfilePictureUri(180, 180)).Into(imgProfile);

            FnInitTabLayout();

            return view;
        }

        void FnInitTabLayout()
        {
            tabLayout.SetTabTextColors(Android.Graphics.Color.Aqua, Android.Graphics.Color.AntiqueWhite);
            //Fragment array
            var fragments = new Fragment[]
            {
                new ActivityFragment(),
                new SportsFragment(),
                new AboutFragment()
            };
            //Tab title array
            var titles = CharSequence.ArrayFromStringArray(new[] {
                "Feed",
                "Sports",
                "About",
            });

            //viewpager holding fragment array and tab title text
            viewpager.Adapter = new ProileTabsAdapter(FragmentManager, fragments, titles);
            tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewpager);
        }

    }
```

When i put it inside an activity and without the above layout only the tab and the viewpager they work perfectly but in this scenario not . Can anyone think of what am i doing wrong ?

EDIT :

Here is the pager adapter

```
 public class ProileTabsAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        private readonly Fragment[] fragments;

        private readonly ICharSequence[] titles;

        public ProileTabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Fragment[] fragments, ICharSequence[] titles) : base(fm)
        {
            this.fragments = fragments;
            this.titles = titles;
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return fragments.Length;
            }
        }

        public override Fragment GetItem(int position)
        {
            return fragments[position];
        }

        public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
        {
            return titles[position];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you implemented adapter for ViewPager? Share the code of your viewpager adapter

Comment: i edited the post to include the adapter

Comment: wrap_content of view pager won't work inside scrollview. try to set layout_height for view pager

Comment: @VinayakB just learned something from you sir .. thnx :)

Comment: add android:fillViewport="true"  into your scrollview . It will also works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use  `android:fillViewport="true"` into your `ScrollView`.
`wrap_content` of view pager won't work inside `Scrollview`.

Comment: you are the savior.

Answer (score 0):

ViewPager doesn't support `width="wrap_content"` or `height="wrap_content"` attrs.

Solutions here : [I am unable to have ViewPager WRAP_CONTENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394681/android-i-am-unable-to-have-viewpager-wrap-content)

You can also use this library : [WCViewPager](https://github.com/rnevet/WCViewPager) (**W**rap **C**ontent **ViewPager**)