# how can my android app programmatically display the keyboard

Tags: android

Is there any way to programmatically tell android to open the keyboard when the focus is obtained by an EditText?

Also is there any way to tell it to open the numeric keyboard?

Thanks
Victor

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open soft keyboard programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593053/open-soft-keyboard-programmatically)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To *show* the keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(viewToEdit, 0);
```

To *hide* the keyboard:

```
if (getCurrentFocus() != null) {
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: This works in general, however I didn't mention that my EditText is in a Dialog, and as soon as I bring up the dialog, the keyboard hides. If I bring up the dialog first, the keyboard doesn't show - any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

To pop up a numeric keyboard on start of the activity you can follow these steps:

Created edit text field in **layout** as: (*Not needed if you want a qwerty keyboard*)

```
 <EditText
        ...
        android:inputType="number"    
        ...  />
```

In function **onCreate()**  show soft keyboard

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
```

Most important is to give focus to edit text in **onResume** method.

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        editText.requestFocus();
    }
```

Comment: I tried this code . When the Activity loads, I can see the focus on the EditText but I can not see the numeric keypad until I click on the EditText. Am I missing something.

Comment: The EditText will take the focus but you have to force keypad to come up. You can write that part in onCreate().

Answer (score 8):

to make it numeric, use this

```
text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

and as far as I know, the keyboard will pop up when needed automatically