# Always On Numeric Keyboard in Android App

Tags: android, keyboard, always-on-top

On a new page (many pages actually) in my app, I want the numeric keyboard to be always on, is this possible?, instead of making individual buttons for each number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it per field, I don't know if you can set it as default though

```
<EditText android:inputType="number" ... />
```

Comment: I have done that, but I want it to be shown without having to click on an edit text item (textbox).

Comment: @user1130327 try calling requestFocus() on your EditText inside your onCreate() method.

Comment: @user1130327 also see [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593053/open-soft-keyboard-programmatically). The second answer seems to indicate that it will show the soft keyboard upon starting an Activity.