# Android softkeyboard not triggerring

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have multiple EditText on my screen and one of them is focussed. The softkeyboard does not trigger as soon as the screen pops up. I want the soft keyboard to trigger as soon as the screen pops up. It works well if I don't implement the **onFocusChangeListener()**. However I need the **onFocusChangeListener()** to detect which editText is focused. I have tried setting setFocusable(true) and setFocusableInTouchMode(true). Also i don't want to modify the  **android:windowSoftInputMode** property in AndroidMenifest.xml. I have the following criteria :

1. onFocusChangeListener implemented (to detect which edittext is focused)
2. No modifications in AndroidMenifest.xml

Here is my code snippet

```
final InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =  (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    mInput.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            mIsFocused = hasFocus;
            if(hasFocus)
                inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(mInput, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

        }
    });
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open softkeyboard programmatically

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0)`.

Source: [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593053/open-soft-keyboard-programmatically%22Stackoverflow%22)