# Android's EditText not opening keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to enable my users to rename a file using the app, my problem is more about the design. I want that when renaming, the EditText will include the old name, and it will be selected, not including the file extension.
I've managed to do that but my problem is that even though the text is selected, the keyboard, and the cursor on the text, are not showing. This makes the user click on the editText to rename it, which cancels the selection, so this is why it really bothers me.
Image for reference:
[image: Image for reference]
My EditText xml (ignore the visibility attribute):

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/renameEditText"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:focusable="true"/>
```

My Code for setting selection:

```
renameEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    String text = renameEdit.getText().toString();
                    if (!text.isEmpty()) {
                        int index = text.lastIndexOf('.');
                        if (index == -1)
                            renameEdit.selectAll();
                        else
                            renameEdit.setSelection(0, index);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Any advices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have set the `selectAll()` or `setSelection()`, you could just pop up the keyboard.

```
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =  (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(renameEdit.getApplicationWindowToken(),     InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, that does some of the job, the cursor on the text still isn't showing though, but that will suffice I guess

Comment: this was helpful, because i only had a reference to the view that was being edited.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to open up the soft keyboard programmatically.

Even a few ways of doing it declaratively in the manifest; however, that requires opening the keyboard on activity start.

**Try this...**

`getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);`

Other possible answers are here - [Open soft keyboard programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593053/open-soft-keyboard-programmatically)

Comment: For some reason the code you've written doesn't open my keyboard but thanks anyway, the link helps :)