# This is my code for onClick method. The toast is displayed but the keyboard doesnt show up

Tags: android, keyboard

I have changed from toggleSoftInput to showSoftInput but no use

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Button Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(MainActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
           imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);            
        }
```

Comment: visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593053/open-soft-keyboard-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(MainActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
}
});
```

this code work fine..
no need to change in that code..

Comment: `SubActionButton Btn1 = itemBuilder.setContentView(icon1).build();
        Btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(MainActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);}});`

using https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu

Answer (score 0):

in onClick of your button hide keyboard first and then show toast next

```
hideKeyboard();
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Button Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

write hideKeyboard method as follows

```
  InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: i actually want the keyboard to be displayed too... I have added toast just for reference to check if the onClick is working... The toast pops up means the onClick is working but the keyboard doesnt show up.. thats the issue..

Comment: try this, go Menu-->Setting -->Apps-->Select your app --> in your app info there is a checkbox called "Show Notification". Enable this to show your app Toast,Disable this to Hide It.