# Android: How to restart an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, restart

I'm trying to restart an Activity in my App, but I have some problems.

When I use `recreate();`, the activity doesn't completely restart, the EditTexts don't get empty.

I also tried this code:

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent();
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
finish();
startActivity(myIntent);
```

**BUT:**

At the start, my Activity have an EditText and it get auto-focus. I'm using this code to open Keyboard when focus, and close when lost focus:

```
txtNumber.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
         if (hasFocus) {
             imm.showSoftInput(txtNumber, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
         } else {
             imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
         }
    }
});
```

But it doesn't works when Activity starts, so i had to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"` to the AndroidManifest.xml.

The problem is that: the 2nd code (for restart the activity) ignore this, and don't open the Keyboard at the start.

How can I open the Keyboard at the Activity Start programmatically? Or how can I completely restart an activity using `recreate();`?

Sorry for bad english, I hope you understand.

Comment: recreate() and call finish(). for older apis (I guess lower 13(?)) startActivity(new Intent(this, getIntent()) and call finish(); and you may put a bundle into the intent, then receive it in onCreate and use it to update/ set up your UI

Comment: try inside oncreate --  (getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);) from here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593053/open-soft-keyboard-programmatically

Comment: Try to txtNumber.requestFocus() after activity restart at onResume

Comment: @MartinPfeffer `recreate()` and `finish()` just close the activity.

Comment: @JuliánPera sorry, my bad... recreate does invoke finish() already..

Comment: first start activtiy and then finish in your 2nd code

Comment: @MartinPfeffer With `recreate()`, the Activity's EditTexts don't get empty.
@Tasos Same result that using `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"`.
@AllenChan Nothing, i also tried turning on the focuseable attribute in the layout.

Comment: @VivekMishra Not found. Keyboard still not open.

Comment: @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
    public void changeKeyboardState() {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
    }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I restart an Android Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397361/how-do-i-restart-an-android-activity)

Answer (score 2):

```
 Try this:
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I tried that. Look at the 2nd code in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

add focusable to your EditText and call requestFocus() when you need to show the the keyboard.

Comment: I guess that EditText is focuseable by default. Anyway, i added `focusable`/`focusableInTouchMode` and put `requestFocus()` in `onResume`, but nothing. Keyboard doesn't show up.

Answer (score -1):

What about this?:

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: This just close the activity.

Comment: I dont know. Im testing this code right now, and it just close the activity. Maybe because the button is inside a DialogAlert?

Comment: The interesting part is, i am using above codes with a `Dialog`(and it's working).let us know your implementation if you want, but above codes are working in my application.