# Android custom dialog class show softkey on startup

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a custom dialog which extends the dialog class.

I have to make it focus one of its edittext and show the softkey on startup of the dialog.

I have looked through several answers which consist of using inputmanager but not so much luck on it.

The activity which calls the dialog is set to hide the softkey by default, which is set on the manifest.

In this case, what can I do about this?

Comment: Edit text to be on focus but you want hide the keypad ??

Comment: In the activity it must not show the softkey.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you on the start_of_the_dialog you should close the keyboard by refrencing this #[SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1109108/2382964) answer. if it doesnt works just add 100ms delay with the help of handler to close the keyboard on the start of dialog.

Answer (score 0):

An assumption first:

By this statement:

> The activity which calls the dialog is set to hide the softkey by default, which is set on the manifest.

Does it mean that it hast the `windowSoftInputMode` attribute like this?

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
...
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
...
</activity>
```

An approach would be to set an `OnShowListener` on the dialog's creation.

1. On your *class-that-extends-Dialog* class you could create an `OnStateListener` and declare it on the constructor like this:

   ```
   public class MyDialog extends Dialog {

       public MyDialog(final Context context) {
           super(context);
           setContentView(R.layout.dialog_mydialog);
           setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {
               @Override
               public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                   displayKeyboard(context);
               }
           });
       }

       private void displayKeyboard(Context context) {
           View view = findViewById(R.id.et_dialog_field);
           InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
                   (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
           inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(
                   view.getApplicationWindowToken(),
                   InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
       }
   }
   ```
2. On the activity I assume you have something like:

   ```
   mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(final View view) {
           MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(MainActivity.this);
           dialog.show();
       }
   });
   ```

The only caveat is that if someone requires to set an `OnShowListener` it will override yours.

I got the *show-soft-input* snippet of code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5617130/1972296).

Answer (score 0):

```
ediText.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        },100);
```