# How to show soft keyboard in focused EditText in a Fragment just after launching Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have `EditText` in a `Fragment` that is shown when my `Activity` is started.

I would like to show show softkeyboard just after the launch.

I've used code from [show-soft-keyboard-when-activity-starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466516/show-soft-keyboard-when-activity-starts) this question in `onStart` method of the Fragment, but it doesn't work.

In which Fragment method I should put this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the best solution was to put `android:windowSoftInputMode=stateVisible` in `Activity` section of `AndroidManifest.xml`

It worked perfectly.