# How to prevent keyboard from opening when activity is opened in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my android app, in my profile edit page, when I start the activity, the first edittext field is focused (blinking cursor), and the keyboard gets displayed.

How can I keep it being focused on startup (blinking cursor) but prevent the keyboard from showing up? If that is not possible, then just not focus the edittext on startup.

Thanks.

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textinput_firstname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="test" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466516/show-soft-keyboard-when-activity-starts

Comment: That question is about showing keyboard and this Question is about hiding keyboard, what makes you think of that as a possible duplicate ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just add this line of code in your `onCreate(...)` method

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: I have to wait 5 minutes before I can... The site wont let me.

Comment: this will break resizing `Activity` feature set by `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` - will behave like `adjustPan` and stop resizing...

Answer (score 2):

This is probably happening for EditText for most users, all you have to do is, just go to the layout file and set the layout's view groups attributes as follows:

```
 android:focusable="true"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

For Example.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"> 
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

> Note: you have to set the attributes for the first view in the layout
> no matter what it is  This will set the default focus to false;